# UITableView row separator issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

My app is composed of `UITableView` with dynamic height rows, all with AutoLayout (programmatically).

My `UITableView` doesn't have any separator, I draw them myself on each row (just one UIView of 1px...). So the `UITableView` is set without any separator.

This works fine. But some random time, especially when there are a lot of different row height in the view, some separation appears between some row. Which make the background (orange) visible and look like a bug (See the image below).

I kinda think it's a bug intern to iOS while managing height of each rows, it could be a value close to 0 that the system try to display and so show 1px height line.

I'm open to every suggestion which could be a solution.

**EDIT**

I added a bigger picture which shows well the problem.
I can't add the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code because it is very complex.
What I can say is that :

- cells 1, 3, 5 are with dynamic height considering their content.
- cells 3, 5 are of the same kind, and reusable between them
- cells 2, 4 are of the same kind, and reusable between them, and with fixed height
- if I don't display rows 2 and 3, the problem doesn't show up (but can i other different situation, it's really kinda random).

**Important note :** The problem doesn't show up on simulator even with exactly the same data.

**EDIT 2**

Here's how I set white background to my cell

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    
self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]];
```

[image: separator issue]

Comment: add cellForRow code to the question

Comment: As @Kabira said, add `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code

Comment: I edited my question to give more information. Sorry the code behind is more than complex to simply copy paste it. But I will do all what I can to answer your questions

Comment: To simplify your problem, if you only have 5 cells, have you tried de-activating cell reuse ?

Comment: I tried without reusing cells, problem stills here

Comment: What do you mean by `Important note : The problem doesn't show up on simulator even with exactly the same data.`? Is the issue only when you test on device?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal exactly

Comment: Just an idea.. Try printing the height and top pixel location of each row and also the height of the tableView on both simulator and device and then see is there is any difference in the values.

Comment: I don't think the image you posted helps communicate the problem.

Comment: @AncAinu Let me know, what exactly the code is written in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is caused by your code providing dynamic cell heights with decimal fraction less than one retina pixel (0.5). Try rounding the value that you return in `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` (if you don't round it already) and see if that helps.

Comment: I blame myself for thought something like it but didn't think it could simply be this. You are right dude ! Thanks for being more intelligent than me :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not more intelligent though :) It's just that I have also had some issues with float values in layout before.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround (not knowing more about your `UITableViewDataSource` methods and `UITableViewCell` implementation) is to change the view behind your tableview to be white. The gaps will still be there but will be the same color as the cells above and below, and therefore not visible.

The problem shown in your image is only with Row 4, correct? What are the orange areas above and below the tableview rows?

If the upper and lower orange areas are not part of the tableview, you could try:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If the orange areas are the header and footer of the tableview, you could set the tableview's `backgroundColor` to white, and then set the views for the header and footer views to have orange backgrounds.